# I can't see thumbnails for JPG images in Plone

Tags: plone, python-imaging-library

I put a lot of images JPG and PNG in a folder. That folder was using the thumbnails view but only PNG images are showed in the thumbnails. I was using Plone 4.1 using a very simple buildout:

```
[buildout]
extends =
    http://dist.plone.org:5021/release/4.1/versions.cfg
parts = instance

[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
user = user:pass
eggs =
    Plone
```

Then I tried to rotate a JPG image and I got the next error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):

Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module Products.ATContentTypes.lib.imagetransform, line 205, in transformImage
Module PIL.Image, line 1676, in transpose
Module PIL.ImageFile, line 189, in load
Module PIL.Image, line 385, in _getdecoder
IOError: decoder jpeg not available
```

So I tried installing libjpeg8 and libjpeg8-dev (with apt-get because I'm working with debian 6). Also I changed the buildout adding the appropiate line for the Pillow egg:

```
[buildout]
extends =
    http://dist.plone.org:5021/release/4.1/versions.cfg
parts = instance

[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
user = user:pass
eggs =
    Plone
    Pillow
```

And now the JPEG thumbnails are displayed.

Thanks for your help. I got a bit confused with buildout at beginning.

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit platform? I've seen problems with images because PIL wanted 32-bit versions of libpng and zlib. (If I remember correctly. That was a year or so ago.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which operating system are you using? Did you compile PIL with JPEG support? You are mostly missing something around those lines, so grab your buildout.cfg and add something like this:

```
...
[instance]
...
eggs =
    PILwoTk
    ...
```

Try running the buildout again in another folder (so that is completely fresh) and try to see what you get when it compiles PILwoTk, to JPEG support to work you should see something like this:

```
# Now you'll see
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# *** TKINTER support not available
# --- JPEG support ok
# --- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok
# --- FREETYPE2 support ok
# -------------------
```

If `JPEG support ok` is not what you get, you are most likely (definitely) missing jpeg development headers.

Comment: These days, I'd use Pillow, rather than PILwoTK or PIL, as it installs on more of the latest platforms.

Comment: I'am using a debian server with 64 bits. I tried installing Pillows again and I have showed the message that JPEG was not supported. Thus, I installed libjpeg8 and then I reinstalled Pillows. After that I get the message "JPEG support OK". I restarted the instance but plone is not rendering JPEG thumbnails.

Comment: Now I tried rotating a JPEG image but I get the next message:

Comment: And don't forget if you do use PILwoTk you need to add the appropriate the find-link because there is no PILwoTk on PyPI. This is partially why Pillow exists, to allow you to do something like the above without worrying about packages' find-links.

Answer (score 0):

Images in Plone are resized during upload. Your formerly uploaded images are not resized or rotated or whatever because the library wasn't there. Now you have a working PIL/Pillow. Re-upload the image and it will work. But you can all images manually in the ZMI. Visit portal_atct and choose the tab 'Image scales'. Then recreate. All images are recalculated. That can last long time depending on the amount of images.